# UITextView resized programmatically but then gets set to old storyboard values.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView that I've positioned and sized in a view via storyboard. I'm using auto layout constraints.
On an iPhone 4s and 5 I've reduced the UITextView's height by setting new frame and bounds for it.  This is so that it won't get covered when the keyboard extends.
When the keyboard extends it seems auto layout is attempting to set its frame and bounds back to what was set in story board (which is for iPhone 6 screens).  After the keyboard extends I can hook into methods to set the height again. However, this results in a somewhat noticeable painting effect.  I.e. it is noticeable that the UITextView extends its height then retracts its height.  I can't find any methods to hook into where I can set the frame & bounds after they have been retrieved from storyboard, but before the UITextView is repainted.  Is there a way to make auto layout use the new frame and bounds that I've set instead of grabbing the one's specified in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting frame, make autolayout constraints available in view controller as `IBOutlet`s and change their constants.

Comment: How do I set an auto-layout constraint for the the UITextView's height? I'm not using auto layout constraints to set the height currently.

Comment: You can add constant for height by selecting UITextView and pressing constraints button in lower right corner of interface builder.

Comment: I will try that later and accept this as the answer if it works.  Thanks!